# Knockoutjs live example does not work on with jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I was wondering why this tutorial using jquery 1.5 works 1.9 it does not ...

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/QSRBR/

```
<div class='liveExample'> 

    <div data-bind='simpleGrid: gridViewModel'> </div>

    <button data-bind='click: addItem'>
        Add item
    </button>

    <button data-bind='click: sortByName'>
        Sort by name
    </button>

    <button data-bind='click: jumpToFirstPage, enable: gridViewModel.currentPageIndex'>
        Jump to first page
    </button>

</div>
```

Any ideas.

thanks

Comment: What is it that doesn't work?

Comment: I don't see any jQuery code in there

Comment: Change the jquery on the left to jQuery 1.9 ... It is on the jsFiddle framework section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/knockoutjs/ewUJjC4AnE8), the problem should have been solved with Knockout 2.2.1. Try to update to the latest stable version of Knockout.

Comment: Can't add a link to JSFiddle in the answer without posting the code, so here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QSRBR/2686/) using the most recent version of Knockout and works even though jQuery 1.9 is referenced as well.

Comment: What did you change if you could briefly mention. I did try to change the knockout 2.2.1 it didn't work .

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper Under the "Manage resources" tab, I removed version 2.1 and added the 2.2.1 version instead. Notice that it have to be referenced prior to the simplegrid-plugin. So you'll have to remove them both and then re add the simplegrid-plugin after you've added the new version of Knockout.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/503

https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/pull/796

looks like jQuery.clean was removed from this release.  knockout was using an undocumented api so this stuff might happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having any problems with jQuery 1.9 or 2.0, please read the following (very important!) changelog: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/.

It is very easy to break legacy code when upgrading to 1.9, especially if using undocumented features.